# TeamCity PowerShell script runner build step runs differently in two projects

Tags: powershell, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I have a PowerShell script that orchestrates a deployment to servers all over the place, but don't fear, it never gets past line 2.

Its the same setup on two project build configurations. However, while it works on one, it fails immediately on another when performing a very early check for a required component.

The script runs a `Get-Command New-SshSession` and checks the output to see if that cmdlet is available, whether the SSH module is setup.

Considering that the same script runs under the same .. I've just worked it out. I'm going to continue on a post an answer!

Anyway, considering the script path is the same, the params are almost the same, how can it fail on one and not on another?

Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the `x86|x64` combobox for the build step is the same for both? Otherwise PowerShell will run from `SysWow64` which has a different modules folder than the 'normal' 64-bit version under `System32`.

Good luck,

Luke